# How to create a schema in sqlite in a spring boot service?

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, flyway

We have a service that supports Oracle and PostgreSQL for persistence already and we use flyway for schema migration. For a new use case we should also support Sqlite.

I now have the issue that Oracle and PostgreSQL both use a schema and all the SQL statements for DDL and inserting test data include this schema as well. I know would like to configure Sqlite in Springboot in a way that I can work with the same schema there as well.

So far I found out that this might work with ATTACH command, but I don't know how to use that with the datasource config and how this will play together with flyway.

Any inputs appreciated.

**Edit**

I'd like to create a table like that in Sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.ta_user (
    id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    valid_from timestamp,
    created timestamp NOT NULL,
    modified timestamp NOT NULL,
    ip varchar(64) ,
    username varchar(255) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```

but I receive

[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (unknown database my_schema)

The reason why I need to have the schema in there is that I have a lot of IT tests where I setup the database with test data using the @SQL annotation and I don't want to provide DB specific test data (as the same scripts now work for oracle and postgresql already)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You simply have to create the migration scripts for SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we didn't find a better solution, we, in the end, created separate sets for DDL and test data with and without schema information. In our use case, SQLite is always used for greenfield setup, which means there is no migration happening, if the schema changes we do it directly in the basic SQL file (not creating a new one). Nevertheless, for all options flyway is used to create the DB. Based on the profile used we decide which set of test data needs to be imported for IT tests, which is then done with ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript

Answer (score 0):

You simply rewrite your migrations with a specific sqlite syntax and place them in their own folder (as you hopefully did for oracle / postgres already) just configure your app (application.yaml / application.properties) to use scripts from that specific sqlite folder.

Comment: Of course we have that already, my issues start when it comes to IT tests where I have @Sql annotation to setup the database with the test data needed. That's why I wanted to have also in Sqlite the same schema